# Accessing pre-populated table on Android, getting error "No such table: TableName"

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I have a prepopulated database that resides in my assets folder and is copied to my /data/data/com.package/database folder when downloaded to the emulator. I am trying to access this database via Phonegap sql calls. I have checked that the table is correctly being ported to the emulator and all of the data is correct. I keep getting an error of table not found however. I am pretty new to app dev so this could be an easy fix. Thanks.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

    var db = window.openDatabase("careerDB.db", "", "Career DB", 60416);
    var careers;
    errorHandler = function(){
        $('#careerList').append('Error!');
    }
    db.transaction(getCareerList);
    function getCareerList(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Careers',[], function(transaction, results) {
            $('#careerList li').remove();
            for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
                var row = results.rows.item(i);
                $('#careerList').append('<li><a href="closestCareers.html?id=' + row['id'] + '"><h4>' + row['career'] + '</h4></a></li>');
            }
            $('#careerList').listview('refresh');
        },errorHandler);
    }
}
```